# Probability of a deviation when Jensen’s inequality is almost tight

Tags: probability-theory, logarithms, convex-analysis, information-theory, jensen-inequality

Let $X>0$ be a random variable. Suppose that we knew that for some $\epsilon \geq 0$,
\begin{eqnarray}
\log(E[X]) \leq E[\log(X)] + \epsilon 
\tag{1} \label{eq:primary}
\end{eqnarray}
The question is: if $\epsilon$ is small, can we find a good bound for
\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left( \log(X) > E[\log(X)] + \eta \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
for a given $\eta > 0$. One bound can be obtained this way:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left( \log(X) > E[\log(X)] + \eta \right) &=&  P\left( X > \exp(E[\log(X)] + \eta) \right) \\
& \leq & E[X] / \exp(E[\log(X)] + \eta)  \\
& = & \exp( \log E[X] - E[\log(X)] - \eta ) \\
& \leq & \exp(\epsilon - \eta)
\end{eqnarray*}
where the first inequality follows from Markov’s inequality. This seems like a good bound due to the exponential decay with $\eta$, but upon closer examination it appears that it can be significantly improved. If we have $\epsilon = 0$, then this bounds gives
\begin{eqnarray}
P\left( \log(X) > E[\log(X)] + \eta \right) & \leq & \exp(-\eta)
\tag{2} \label{eq:good_but_not_best}
\end{eqnarray}
However, from Jensen's inequality applied to (\ref{eq:primary}) with $\epsilon = 0$ we obtain $\log(E[X]) = E[\log(X)]$ and therefore $X$ is a constant almost everywhere. As a consequence, for any $\eta>0$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left( \log(X) > E[\log(X)] + \eta \right) = 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
which is (of course) infinitely better than (\ref{eq:good_but_not_best}).

It would appear that a better bound should decay to zero as $\epsilon$ decays, and ideally preserve the exponential decay with $\eta$. Any suggestions?

Comment: I couldn't follow why $\epsilon=0$ in (1) gives equality in Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Jensen implies that $\log E X \geq E \log X$ which combined with (1) and $\epsilon = 0$ gives the equality.

Comment: I did not notice the opposite sign. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cross-posted on Math Overflow and quickly obtained a very nice answer. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377913/probability-of-a-deviation-when-jensen-s-inequality-is-almost-tight